# Damaged and/or poorly installed light switches and outlet boxes

Tags: drywall, switch

What is The Right Way to repair the drywall above this switch box?

The problem is that the metal box pictured here is not mounted correctly, and wobbles a bit. This would not be too bad of an issue if I could rely on the "eyehole looking part" of the light switch to make contact with the drywall, and thus pull the box tight when the switch is screwed in.

Should I cut out a rectangular area of drywall right above the box and put a fresh chunk in with a board to back it? Cut out a larger area and redo the box itself, along with the drywall cut?

I know there are metal/plastic backing plate type things I could put between the drywall and the switch, and I've used them elsewhere - but I can't quite find on that fits in this situation, without going well over the size of the switch face plate (which my wife is fond of).

Edit: I mean this question more in the abstract sense - this is just one of many of this sort of issue throughout my house, and I would like to repair them all.

[image: drywall damage around the electrical box]

Comment: What is that box mounted to? A stud? The drywall?

Comment: If the cover plate of the switch can fit firmly against the wall, after tighten the screw (which pulls the box towards the plate, at the same time, pushes the plate against the wall), the box shouldn't be wobbling then.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, it is mounted to a stud further left, albeit loosely. I cannot quite reach the screws to tighten it. I get the impression that this is actually a dual gang box, where someone may have snipped off the screw holes on the left side in an attempt to make it fit during a renovation (rather than replacing the dual box with a single).

Comment: @r13 I think I have a different type of switch/cover plate - the switch is the only thing that screws into the box, and the cover plate screws into the switch itself. If it were not missing the top chunk of drywall, then yeah, screwing the switch in real tight would do the trick.